# Why do colons not work in pandas iloc if slicing on the basis of both rows & columns

Tags: pandas, slice

`df.iloc[[1,4], [1,6]]` works, but what if I want rows
`[1:4]` inclusive, and columns `[1:6]` inclusive?

I know I can list the rows/columns that I want eg `df.iloc[[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4,5,6]]`

but what if the quantity of rows/columns makes this impractical, say, it was `[7:50]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`df.iloc[[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4,5,6]]` is equivalent to `df.iloc[1:5, 1:7]`, or `df.iloc[1:4+1, 1:6+1]`